# c++ shared_ptr error with intel 12.1.3

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

With gcc 4.6.1 I use the following typedef

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_Ptr;
```

I included `<memory>` and compile it with `-std=c++0x` and all is fine.

With intel 12.1.3 the same code also compiled with `-std=c++0x` gives the error

```
test_intel_gcc.cpp(7): error: qualified name is not allowed
  typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_Ptr;
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <memory>

class A;

typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_Ptr; 

class A {
public:     
  A() {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A_Ptr ap;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `A` and do you get the same error if you try an `shared_ptr<int>` for example?

Comment: Code added to show a minimal example.

Answer (score 3):

The EDG front end (which the Intel compiler uses) gives that error when you use an undeclared, qualified name in a typedef.  So it implies `std::shared_ptr` is not declared in `<memory>`, which implies either you forgot to use `-std=c++0x` (but you say you used that) or your Intel compiler is using the headers from an older version of GCC (not your 4.6.1 installation) which doesn't provide `shared_ptr`.

You should be able to verify you get the same error by changing the template-id to one that definitely isn't declared:

```
#include <memory>

class A;

typedef std::xxx_shared_ptr<A> A_Ptr;
```